# Effects of the flywheel having broken teeth, Toyota Camry

Tags: toyota, starter, camry, flywheel

It seems like my car no longer moves as quickly or as easily when it is in 3rd gear.  I suspect the flywheel, hence the question: What does the flywheel effect if it has missing teeth? I have done a tune up, replaced the starter, but the starter might be defective. Also how do you tell if the starter *is* defective?

So two questions:

- What effects would missing teeth on the flywheel have?
- How can I tell if the starter is defective?

Comment: Could you please use punctuation? The post is very difficult to read.

Comment: The starter will not affect performance while the car is running. Once the engine is started, the starter is completely disengaged from the flywheel. This is also not a flywheel question. Also, do they even make a Camry with a manual transmission? If not, you have a flex plate, not a flywheel.

Answer (score 2):

A broken tooth or teeth on the flywheel will cause issues when engaging the starter.  it will slip and possibly damage the starter.

The easiest way to test the starter is to remove it and take it to the local auto parts store.  If you think the teeth are bad, you should be able to use a screwdriver or a pick to pull the gear out and look at the teeth.

an issue with the starter or flywheel would not cause an issue in 3rd gear that does not exist in other gears.